# Creating nested soap header

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to create a nested header like this:

```
            var eab = new EndpointAddressBuilder(contributor.Endpoint.Address);

            eab.Headers.Add(AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader("useridentity",
                    "scheme",
                    "<uid xmlns=\"scheme2\">Some_User_ID</uid>"));
```

but this way my inner xml tag gets escaped with `&lt;` and I get `& lt; uid` instead of `<uid ...` How do I disable this escaping and treat this string as XML?